Can we construct an isomorphism between $\mathrm{BS}(1,n)$ and $\mathbb{Z}[1/n]\rtimes\mathbb{Z}$ such that it preserve the order?
It is given in Regular left-orders on groups that the solvable Baumslag-Solitar group $\mathrm{BS}(1,n)=\langle a, b\mid aba^{-1}=b^n\rangle $ is isomorphic to  $\mathbb{Z}[1/n]\rtimes \mathbb{Z}$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}.$ Can we find an isomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Z}[1/n]\rtimes \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathrm{BS}(1,n) $ such that if $u<v$ implies $\phi(u)<\phi(v),$ where $u,v\in\mathbb{Z}[1/n]\rtimes \mathbb{Z}$.
Let $u=(r,m)$ and $v=(r',m')$ so $u<v$ means $(r,m)<(r',m')$ which happens if either $m'>m$ or if $m=m'$ then $r'>r.$
In BS(1,n) every element can be written as can be
written in the form $a^n(a^{-m}b^ka^m)$with $m\geq 0$, $n, k \in \mathbb{Z}$. So I guess $a^{n_1}(a^{-{m_1}}b^{k_1}a^{m_1})>a^{n_2}(a^{-{m_2}}b^{k_2}a^{m_2})$ if either $n_1>n_2$ or if $n_1=n_2$ then $m_1>m_2.$ I am not sure about the ordering in $BS(1,n)$. When can we determine that one element is lesser than another in $BS(1,n)$?)

Your last sentence seems to be truncated. You need to specify orders on both groups for the question to make sense.

Is $b^2$ bigger than $b$  in the order on $BS(1,n)$ ?

In $\mathbb{Z}[1/n]\rtimes\mathbb{Z}$ , $b^2$ is greater than $b$, but i am not sure in BS(1,n).

In order for your question to be well-posed, one still need to define how $\mathbb Z$ acts on $\mathbb Z[\frac1n]$: is $(0,1)(1,0)(0,1)^{-1}=(n,0)$ or $(\frac1n,0)$?

The elements of the group $\mathbb{Z}[1/n]\rtimes\mathbb{Z}$ are pairs $(r,m),$ where $r\in \mathbb{Z}[1/n]$ and $m\in\mathbb{Z}.$
The multiplication is defined as
$(r,m)(r',m') = (r + q^m\cdot r',m + m').$

I guess $q=n$ (?)

yeah .sorry typing mistake. It's n. Thank you.

First, following your answer in comments, I assume that $(0,1)(1,0)(0,1)^{-1}=(n,0)$, so that the map $\phi\colon \mathbb Z[\frac1n]\rtimes\mathbb Z\to BS(1,n)$, defined by $\phi(0,1)=a$ and $\phi(1,0)=b$ and more generally
$$\phi(r,m)=a^m(a^{-q}b^pa^q)$$
where $p\in\mathbb Z$ and $q\in\mathbb Z_{\ge 0}$ such that $r=\frac{p}{n^q}$ is an isomorphism.
Then the order you propose on $BS(1,n)$ is not well-defined. There are two issues:

First $b=a^{-1}b^na$, so if I follow correctly you would declare $b<a^{-1}b^na$, despite the two elements being equal (here I assume $n\ge 2$).
Second one has $a^{-1}ba=a^{-2}b^na^2$. If $n<0$, you would declare this element both larger (first expression) and smaller (second expression) than $e$.

In order to define the order on $BS(1,n)$, the easiest is to just define when an element is larger than $e$. In this case, one define $a^m(a^{-q}b^pa^q)>e$ if $m>0$ or ($m=0$, $q$ is even and $p>0$). We can then extends this order to get a right-invariant order: $g>h$ iff $gh^{-1}>e$. This coincides with the "push-forward" (via $\phi$) of the right-order defined on $\mathbb Z[\frac1n]\rtimes\mathbb Z$, i.e., the answer is "Yes".
(If you want to directly define the order on $BS(1,n)$, you need to force $m_1=m_2$ to avoid the first problem, and be careful about the parity of $m_1,m_2,n_1,n_2$ to avoid the second.)

Is this isomorphism true if we take $n<-1$, I did not get any article where it is proved for negative $n.$ Almost everywhere this isomorphism is proved for $n$ positive and when $n\geq2$ this group $BS(1,n)$ is an ordered group. Am I right?

But yes, $\phi$ is an isomorphism regardless of the sign of $n$.

Can you tell me more about ordering in BS(1,n)? In $\mathbb{Z}[1/n]\rtimes\mathbb{Z}$ it is easy to see when one element is lesser than another, (like (r,m)<(r',m') if either m>m'or r'>r). But I am not sure how to see this in BS(1,n). Is it a little bit complicated or simple?

Will it hold if we take only positive element?

The easiest way to think about this order is through the isomorphism. You have an isomorphism with a left-ordered group, you can just "pullback" the order.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
